# Not able to import sbt dependency for shc-core

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, hbase

I'm trying to connect to hbase using spark and I want to use hortonworks shc but I'm not able to import sbt dependency for shc-core (I'm able to import shc though). Following is the built.sbt snapshot-

```
name := "untitled"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.2"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.2"

resolvers += "Hortonworks Repository" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.shc/shc
libraryDependencies += "com.hortonworks.shc" % "shc" % "1.1.0.3.0.2.0-50" pomOnly()

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.shc/shc-core
libraryDependencies += "com.hortonworks.shc" % "shc-core" % "1.1.0.3.0.2.0-50"
```

I'm getting following error (starting few lines not included)-

```
[info] Resolving org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;working@ashish-HP-Notebook ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;working@ashish-HP-Notebook ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;working@ashish-HP-Notebook
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ashish/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/working@ashish-HP-Notebook/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/working@ashish-HP-Notebook/hadoop-aws-working@ashish-HP-Notebook.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/ashish/.sbt/preloaded/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/working@ashish-HP-Notebook/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/ashish/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/working@ashish-HP-Notebook/hadoop-aws-working@ashish-HP-Notebook.pom
[warn] ==== Hortonworks Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/working@ashish-HP-Notebook/hadoop-aws-working@ashish-HP-Notebook.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1!jcip-annotations.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.pom
[warn]  :: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1!guava.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.pom
[warn]  :: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0!guice-assistedinject.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.pom
[warn]  :: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.9: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.9!logback-classic.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.9/logback-classic-1.0.9.pom
[warn]  :: ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.9: ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.9!logback-core.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.0.9/logback-core-1.0.9.pom
[warn]  :: org.apache.thrift#libthrift;0.9.0: org.apache.thrift#libthrift;0.9.0!libthrift.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.0/libthrift-0.9.0.pom
[warn]  :: it.unimi.dsi#fastutil;6.5.6: it.unimi.dsi#fastutil;6.5.6!fastutil.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/6.5.6/fastutil-6.5.6.pom
[warn]  :: org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2: org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2!antlr-runtime.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.pom
[warn]  :: sqlline#sqlline;1.2.0: sqlline#sqlline;1.2.0!sqlline.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/sqlline/sqlline/1.2.0/sqlline-1.2.0.pom
[warn]  :: org.iq80.snappy#snappy;0.3: org.iq80.snappy#snappy;0.3!snappy.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.3/snappy-0.3.pom
[warn]  :: org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.0: org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.0!commons-csv.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.0/commons-csv-1.0.pom
[warn]  :: org.ow2.asm#asm;5.0.4: org.ow2#ow2;1.3!ow2.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;working@ashish-HP-Notebook: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:working@ashish-HP-Notebook
[warn]        +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.0.0.3.0.2.0-50
[warn]        +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-replication:2.0.0.3.0.2.0-50
[warn]        +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:2.0.0.3.0.2.0-50
[warn]        +- org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:5.0.0.3.0.2.0-50
[warn]        +- com.hortonworks.shc:shc-core:1.1.0.3.0.2.0-50 (/home/ashish/sparkprojects/untitled/build.sbt#L20-21)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1: com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1!jcip-annotations.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.pom
[error] unresolved dependency: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1!guava.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.pom
[error] unresolved dependency: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0!guice-assistedinject.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/ashish/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.pom
```

I'm using spark 2.2.2 and sbt .13 and using ubuntu.

Also, when I'm doing this in windows, I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library imports have been incorrectly specified. According to [documentation](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc#configuring-spark-package), just importing `shc-core` should suffice as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += “com.hortonworks/shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11”
```

Also, note that adding `pomOnly()` to your build.sbt will make handlers skip any jar libs or artifacts for this dependency. Adding it will get you only metadata from the aggregate pom.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a scala dependency so you should make sbt take care of the scala version like with spark. Using double %%

```
libraryDependencies += "com.hortonworks.shc" %% "shc" % "1.1.0.3.0.2.0-50"
```

Comment: If I'm adding %% instead of % then it is prefixing scala version i.e. 2.11 and due to this it is not able to find the dependency.